GCP storage server certificate verification
I think for AWS, this relates to
https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/
what's the equivalent for verifying certificates used on GCP storage URLs, e.g.
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage_path_name
in cases where the client machine is not trusting the Google server hostname in the giving storage URL. I couldn't find anything online about this so far. I asked on Google's online community and got this response:

Google Cloud doesn't provide a centralized repository like the one you mentioned for AWS. Instead, it relies on standard certificate authorities. If there are specific concerns or issues, reaching out to Google Cloud Support can also be helpful for assistance tailored to your specific situation.

Just posting here as well in case there's any additional feedback I can get.

I think it's the same. AFAIK Google doesn't provide something like AWS. The best would be downloading the certificates manually but apart from that there's nothing similar
